# Yii Validation; combining validators with OR logic

Tags: validation, yii

Yii built-in validation returns invalid if one of the set of validators in the array fails,

e.g.

```
array( 
  array('A', 'required'),
  array('B', 'required')
)
```

will return invalid if either A or B is empty. (AND logic)

I would like to combine these validators so that it will return invalid only if all individual validators return invalid (OR logic). 
The example above would return invalid only in the case that both A and B are empty.

Is there a generic built-in way to do this?

If not I am expecting to have to extend the library to handle something like the following:

```
array(
  array('', 'COrValidator', 
    array('A', 'required'),
    array('B', 'required')
  )
)
```

Comment: I'd say it's the other way round. You're condition *"if either A or B is empty"* already implies that currently it's an OR combination of validators. Validation fails if A OR B fails. You want a AND logic. That's not available from the core, so you're assumption is right. You have to write a custom `AndValidator`.

Comment: Only if you are using negative logic.  Say pass is true and fail is false.  For the required validator empty is the fail or false condition. A and B is true if A is true and B is true, but A and B is false if A is false or B is false, or to use the required validator terminology A and B fails if A is empty OR B is empty.  so it looks like Arth was correct after all!

Comment: @Michael, I was looking at the pass conditions as jmarkmurphy points out. As the custom validator would be validating a situation where either statement X or statement Y could be true to pass, I would call it an OrValidator.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to create an AnyValidValidator so that you can do something like this:

```
array(
   array('attribute1, attibute2', 'anyValid', array('required')),
);
```

The problem with

```
array(
  array('', 'COrValidator', 
    array('A', 'required'),
    array('B', 'required')
  )
)
```

is that, without significant modification of the validator functionality, the COrValidator validator will not be applied to any attributes (no attributes specified).

Comment: An interesting solution, but i would need something more generic so that validation X could involve required and validation Y could be a range for example.

Comment: Do you have a specific requirement in mind, or is this just speculation?

Comment: It is a generic requirement (i.e. multiple complex validation scenarios in which this would be used), so not just speculation; but another method using different parts of the framework could be considered!

Comment: Just thinking out loud here, but maybe, since validators are Components, there is a way to inject a behavior that would allow for an Any Valid component.  If so you could accomplish your goal without having to make modifications to the base validator class.  Something like array('field list', 'required', array('behavior'=>anyValid('group1'))).